# Could not find or load main Exception

Tags: java, git, maven

I have downloaded a git repository from this  url : https://github.com/tamingtext/book.git , whenever i run the shell  that exist in bin directory with this command :

```
./frankenstein.sh
```

it shows me this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tamingtext.frankenstein.Frankenstein
```

i suspected that i missed some dependancy so i downloaded maven and tried to build the code with this command :

```
mvn package
```

but still i get the same error.
can someone tell what i've missed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in README exactly?

Comment: No, i've forgotten about it , i thought the shell will do the rest.i will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building the project correctly, but for the CLASSPATH to work as expected, you have to run `bin/frankenstein.sh` from the project's root directory, and ***not*** `./frankenstein.sh` from `bin` as you do.

Comment: thanks, i get now some errors because i didn't rightly build the project thanks for your help.